# DHT11 temperature and humidity pull up resistor

Tags: arduino, resistors

I am setting up my Arduino Due with the DHT11 temperature and humidity sensor.  Most diagrams mention using a 10k ohm sensor.  Is it OK to use a 5.1k ohm as that's what I have available?

Comment: You need to do the calculations and see what the potential divider gives you in each case. You should find the values of resistance in the datasheet (which should be hyperlinked in your question). Add in your calculations and we can check them.

Comment: Why not just use two 5,1k resistors in series?

Comment: Maybe you should put one of the "most diagrams" on your question as well. As it looks unclear what's this about.

Answer (score 1):

5.1K is what is recommended by the manufacturer (Aosong Guangzhou Electronics Co) under normal conditions.

High cable capacitance might require a lower value.